# Servers, cloud and network

Tags: networking, cluster, cloud, server-setup

I need so help so I have few questions. I work in small company and we are going to be buying one or two servers for our needs. We are in area that isn't well equip with internet (only ADSL or WiMAX) so we want our own network that isn't relying on internet access. We have client-server software that lets us do everything from accounting to keeping track of materials we received for production.  So : Can these 2 servers be in cloud and "share" same data (data from accounting software and archived data that we want to keep) so in case one fails other one keeps going and we don't lose any data that way? Can we also use them for File storage and Sharing? Also can they be made into host server for our company site? Can they do all that? Is two of them overkill?

Comment: A) I don't think you understand what 'cloud' means, I think you mean 'cluster', B) possibly yes but it depends on what software and services you're looking at and you've not provided 1% of the information we'd need and C) I may be wrong but perhaps you're out of your depth on this, you may need someone with experience doing this to help you.

Answer (score -1):

if you don't want to rely on an Internet connection then am I right in thinking these two servers will be on premise? if so what I would suggest is setting up your two servers as Hyper-V host serves in a two node cluster. you would then create virtual machines on the cluster to run your applications. if you are using server 2012 or 2012 R2 you will need some shared storage, this storage will be used to store you virtual machines and their data. with this setup if one of your host servers fail the other will take over the running of its clustered resources.

Comment: OP doesn't mention preferred OS, they could be a 100% Linux/Solaris/OSX house for all we know.